# YAML Error ERROR: while parsing a block mapping in “<unicode string>”,

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

im trying to compose my docker with this YAML:

```
web:
  image: php:7.2-apache
  environment:
    - ALLOW_OVERRIDE=true
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  links:
    - db
  volumes:
    - ./app:/var/www/html/

db:
  image: mariadb
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_USER: admin
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
    MYSQL_DATABASE: database
  ports:
    - "889:3306"


 phpmyadmin:
   image: phpmyadmin
   container_name: phpmyadmin
   environment:
     - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
   restart: always
   ports:
     - 8080:80
   volumes:
     - /sessions
   links:
     - db
```

But when i execute the docker-compose this error appears:

ERROR:

```
while parsing a block mapping
  in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 1:
    web:
    ^
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "<unicode string>", line 26, column 2:
     phpmyadmin:
     ^
```

Y don't really know how to solve :( I saw in this website that it's maybe because of the writting but i dont know how it should be

Comment: Is this your entire docker-compose file ? Because if yes, it is clearly not respecting the standard described in documentation. It should declare a version, all your services should be declared under the `services` option. Moreover, it looks like indentation is inconsistent (indentation is absolutelly meaningfull in yaml). If This is not your entire yaml file, please edit your question and update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In docker-compose, you have to define versions and services:

```
version: '2'
services: 
  web:
    image: php:7.2-apache
    environment:
      - ALLOW_OVERRIDE=true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html/

  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
    ports:
      - "889:3306"


  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /sessions
    links:
      - db
```